# Can you make a multistage roots vacuum pump quieter by putting something on the exhaust?

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum

The multistage roots pump in our lab is really loud, currently, there is nothing on the exhaust, as we are just dealing with air. Does somebody know a way to make the pump quieter (i already proposed putting it in the anteroom of the lab)? Is the pump louder when the exhaust is left free like that?

Comment: You can, of course, put a muffler on it. That increases the backpressure on the exhaust which will impact pump performance. You can also enclose the pump in a box with acoustic absorbing material. However, I have never worked in a lab that exhausted vacuum pumps into the lab - it always was plumbed in an exhaust duct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the "muffler" should be tuned to the fundamental tone of the blower spectrum, which will be (lobe shaft RPM) x 60 x (number of lobes on the shaft). You do this by lining the outlet duct with dissipative material (fiberglass mats) at the point along the duct length corresponding to a velocity maximum. If the blower housing/motor assembly is bolted to the floor, you may also need to shockmount the assembly off the floor with rubber biscuits. Rubber blocks used for automobile engine motor mounts are excellent for this purpose.